# *ngFor table in Angular stop condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an array similar to this :

```
tableData = [
{claimId: "C.24NNT.001.001", MON: "8h", WED: "3h10m ", FRI: "5h20m "},
{claimId: "unspecified", TUE: "8h", WED: "4h50m ", FRI: "2h40m "},
{claimId: "C.24NNT.005.001", THU: "8h"},]
```

This is what I've done so far:

[image]

I want to rowspan the cells under Total and stop after 1 execution of ngFor.

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <thead class="header">
    <th>WBS.ELEMENT</th>
    <th *ngFor="let day of tableHeader">{{day}}</th>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData">
      <td>
        {{row.claimId}}
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let day of tableHeader">{{row[day]}}</td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="tableData.length">{{weeklyHours}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

tableHeader inside component :

```
tableHeader: string[] = ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'];
```

How do I break out of weekly hours so it doesn't generate outside the table?

Comment: i won't post as answer as I think there will be a better way but you could use the `first` local template value of the `ngFor` directive and style non-first elements as hidden. Use looks like `*ngFor="let day of tableHeader; let first = first"`. Other local variables are `index, odd, even` and `last`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply apply an index to the `*ngFor` loop, like so:

```html
<tr *ngFor = "let row of tableData; let i = index">
    <td>
        {{row.claimId}}
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let day of tableHeader">{{row[day]}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="i === 0" [attr.rowspan]="tableData.length">{{weeklyHours}}</td>
</tr>
```

Note that there are also other identifiers next to `index`. You may want to have a look at [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/) to get a better understanding of what you can do with `*ngFor`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: for some reason the elvis operator didn't work for me ,but I used *ngIf="i === 0" and it worked.Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer, that others might benefit from it as well. I am glad it helped you.